# File Upload/Download module in PHP

Tags: php

I have a online PHP application to which I want that the Admin should be able to upload files at file system using PHP / HTML forms and the other users can download the files. The application should log the number of downloads for a specific file. The files should appear in proper folders as organized by the admin.

I am searching for such a module that should be able to do these generic tasks.

If you know such then please share your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a PHP application. Build a uploader module to it, it won't be a difficult task. 
If you want a standalone app here is it : http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/

Comment: Thanks Stewie! Thats really very nice!

Comment: You are welcome. if you are satisfied with the answer choose it as the answer, select the "checkmark" next to this answer below votes

Comment: OK i have done that! Thanks for guiding too! Actually, I am new on stackoverflow.